# Error in SSMS when running query from SQL On-Demand endpoint

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am attempting to pull in data from a CSV file that is stored in an Azure Blob container and when I try to query the file I get an error of

`File 'https://<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/Sales/2020-10-01/Iris.csv' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.`

The file does exist and as far as I know of it is not being used by anything else.

I am using SSMS and also a SQL On-Demand endpoint from Azure Synapse.

What I did in SSMS was run the following commands after connecting to the endpoint:

1. `CREATE DATABASE [Demo2];`
2. `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureBlob WITH ( LOCATION 'wasbs://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/' )`
3. ```
   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
           BULK 'Sales/2020-10-01/Iris.csv',
           DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob',
           FORMAT = '*'
           ) AS tv1;
   ```

I am not sure of where my issue is at or where to go next. Did I mess up anything with creating the external data source? Do I need to use a SAS token there and if so what is the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I haven't tried Armando's suggestion yet.

First I had to go to the container and edit IAM policies to give my Active Directory login a Blob Data Contributor role. The user to give access to will be your email address for logging in to your portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/synapse-analytics/toc.json&bc=/azure/synapse-analytics/breadcrumb/toc.json

After that I had to re-connect to the On-Demand endpoint in SSMS. Make sure you login through the Azure AD - MFA option. Originally I was using the On-Demand endpoint username and password which was not given access to the Blob Data Contributor role for the container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@Ubiquitinoob44, you need to create a database credential:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=shared-access-signature

Comment: Thanks Armando, I figured out a different solution to my problem posted above.